# Run Node from Heroku Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

I have a rails app that allows users to write code (sort of like those teach yourself coding) using [sandcastle](https://github.com/bcoe/sandcastle/) (a node library).

I have a node script which does what I want it to, but how can I trigger it to run from my rails app on heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two apps.  Create a separate node app on Heroku and provide endpoints that your Rails app can communicate with.  I think that is your best bet as you cannot run ruby & node on the same dyno at Heroku.

Comment: But since these are cross domain, I'd have to use JSONP right? Which means I would only be able to send data via GET...

Comment: Only if you plan to make the request via javascript.  You can always make the request server-side

Comment: That is true. I guess proxying will work fine for now. Thanks